# Ubuntu 20.10 Upgrade - Terminal Stutter

Tags: 20.10

I have upgraded from 20.04 to 20.10 and ever since the Gnome Terminal stutters randomly. The terminal generally feels slower than normal, but the main annoyance is when I run a command and the screen does not update. To force a update to the screen I have to press another key.

I generally I use tmux, zsh, and oh my zsh.

I have experimented with multiple Nvidia drivers & used bash rather than zsh, but I haven't been successful in the finding the issue.

Any thoughts or suggestions would be awesome.